# Shall I keep excel workbook connection open in C# or open a new one every time I need to add a new row?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have implemented a download utility which downloads files in background thread.Now, I want to implement functionality to export the download results for each file to an excel sheet. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library for this purpose.So, for this I create an excel workbook, and do entries in it.My issue is whether I open a workbook at the start of the download process, and close the workbook when the process is finished or shall I create a new excel connection every time I want to do an entry? Please, note that the downloads can take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to bear in mind with `Interop` usage is that you are actually creating an `excel.exe` process in the background and then using DCOM to manipulate the running process.

Typically, this means when you open a file for the first time and Excel is not running, it will take time to load. I would therefore suggest keeping the file open in the background if you are going to be doing incremental updates.

Also remember that Interops are hardcoded to the version of Office you are targetting and also require Office to be installed to function.

Personally, I always use 3rd party libraries for Excel manipulation as they are much more performant than the `Interop` assemblies and don't have the hard-dependency of needing Office installed on the machine.

Examples I've used successfully are: [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) and [FlexCel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcel.asp)

Comment: I am using version 15 of Interop assembly, so will that work with a specific version of excel.

Comment: It'll work with the version that version 15 corresponds to. It might work with earlier versions but is not guaranteed to. MS regularly mess around with the exposed API between versions which is why so many 3rd party libraries exist that run off the file format rather than the Office API version.

Comment: You were absolutely write, interop library is absolute crap, I used NPOI, and it is working really well.